# R - Keep log of all plots

Tags: r

I do a lot of data exploration in R and I would like to keep every plot I generate (from the interactive R console). I am thinking of a directory where everything I plot is automatically saved as a time-stamped PDF. I also do not want this to interfere with the normal display of plots.

Is there something that I can add to my `~/.Rprofile` that will do this?

Comment: If you're using ggplot, you could run `ggsave` after every plot (or incorporate it in a function where you add a file name with a time stamp).

Comment: RStudio have functionality where it automatically keeps track of all plots made in the session - I don't know if it saves them externally to a temporary location though.  You can also do something similar in the Windows RGui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could write your own wrapper functions for your commonly used plot functions. This wrapper function would call both the on-screen display and a timestamped pdf version. You could `source()` this function in your ~/.Rprofile so that it's available every time you run R.

For latice's xyplot, using the `windows` device for the on-screen display:

```
library(lattice)
my.xyplot <- function(...){
    dir.create(file.path("~","RPlots"))
    my.chart <- xyplot(...)
    trellis.device(device="windows",height = 8, width = 8)
    print(my.chart)
    trellis.device(device = "pdf",
                   file = file.path("~", "RPlots",
                   paste("xyplot",format(Sys.time(),"_%Y%m%d_%H-%M-%S"),
                         ".pdf", sep = "")),
                   paper = "letter", width = 8, height = 8)
    print(my.chart)
    dev.off()
}

my.data <- data.frame(x=-100:100)
my.data$y <- my.data$x^2

my.xyplot(y~x,data=my.data)
```

As others have said, you should probably get in the habit of working from an R script, rather than working exclusively from the interactive terminal. If you save your scripts, everything is reproducible and modifiable in the future. Nonetheless, a "log of plots" is an interesting idea.

Comment: This seems like the way to go.

Comment: Not as it just saves the plot _realizations_ and not how to recreate them.  Trust me, you _will_ want to modify something, change the title, change a color, ...  You do want the code.

Answer (score 7):

The general idea is to write a *script* generating the plot in order to regenerate it. The ESS  documentation (in a README) says it well under 'Philosophies for using ESS':

> The source code is    real.  The objects are realizations of the
>   source code.  Source    for EVERY user modified object is placed in a
>   particular directory    or directories, for later editing and
>   retrieval.

With any editor allows stepwise (or regionwise) execution of commands you can keep track of your work this way.

Answer (score 4):

The best approach is to use a script file (or sweave or knitr file) so that you can just recreate all the graphs when you need them (into a pdf file or other).

But here is the start of an approach that does the basics of what you asked:

```
savegraphs <- local({i <- 1; 
    function(){
      if(dev.cur()>1){
        filename <- sprintf('graphs/SavedPlot%03d.pdf', i)
        dev.copy2pdf( file=filename )
        i <<- i + 1
      }
    }
})

setHook('before.plot.new', savegraphs )

setHook('before.grid.newpage', savegraphs )
```

Now just before you create a new graph the current one will be saved into the graphs folder of the current working folder (make sure that it exists).  This means that if you add to a plot (`lines`, `points`, `abline`, etc.) then the annotations will be included.  However you will need to run `plot.new` in order for the last plot to be saved (and if you close the current graphics device without running another `plot.new` then that last plot will not be saved).

This version will overwrite plots saved from a previous R session in the same working directory.  It will also fail if you use something other than base or grid graphics (and maybe even with some complicated plots then).  I would not be surprised if there are some extra plots on occasion that show up (when internally a plot is created to get some parameters, then immediatly replaced with the one of interest).  There are probably other things that I have overlooked as well, but this might get you started.