# Automaticly capture plots send to windows() device in r

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to capture all plots a user makes in a script and save it in a folder. I have tried `png("C:/path/to/plotfolder/Rplot%03d.png")` and it works great for most plots. Unfortunately the department got alot of functions that use the `windows()` function. Those plots are not captured, and I've been unable to find a function that can capture plots send to those devices.

```
png("path/to/somewhere/plot.png")
windows()
plot(1:20)
dev.off()
```

This creates an empty file called plot.png.

I would really like to avoid forcing users to avoid those functions or rewrite them, so is there any way  to capture plots send to a `windows()` device with a single call as in `png()`? If this is not the case, I guess i will have to just remove the `windows()` calls from the scripts or something.

#### Extra information

I need this since i'm trying to create a rscript function that runs a script and saves all output including warnings,errors, prints and plots to a specific folder that can then later be opened by another application. I would like not to interfere with the users code forcing them to make alternate functions when working with this script.

edit

Tried looking into knitr, as it seems to be able to find and save plots in `windows()` devices, but so far i have been unable to find anything. UPDATE: Not compatible with what i want

edit

I have found something that could work sometimes, but not a solution. Using `savePlot` in a while loop could save all open windows, but if several plots have been send to the device it will only save the last

Comment: `windows()` is calling a new device, so the `png` device doesn't see the plot. You could try overwriting the `windows` function which should work providing it isn't referenced with its namespace

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436282/r-keep-log-of-all-plots

Comment: It's kind of a solution, but it would require alot of code, and every time a new kind of plot is used,  would have to update the script for every user. This is not just something that i would have on my own computer

Comment: Somehow i managed to miss your comment @James. Created a simple wrapper, but would still like to know if capturing the plots in another way was possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found somewhat of a solution, though i would like a better solution. Since it's an supposed to run as an rscript i just replaced `windows()` with a wrapper for `png()`. As

```
windows <- function (width = 480, height = 480, pointsize = 12, record, rescale, xpinch, 
  ypinch, bg = "white", canvas, gamma, xpos, ypos, buffered, title, restoreConsole = TRUE, 
  clickToConfirm, fillOddEven, family = "sans", antialias = c("default", "none", "cleartype", "grey", "subpixel"),
  filename = plotoutput) {
  png(filename,width,height,pointsize,bg,restoreConsole,family,antialias)
}
```

Thanks for the help James.